# Period of $[x]^2+\sqrt{\{x\}^2}$

Tags: solution-verification, periodic-functions

> Find the period of $[x]^2+\sqrt{\{x\}^2}$, where $[.]$ represents greatest integer function of $x$ and $\{x\}$ represents fractional part of $x$.

$\sqrt{\{x\}^2}$ can be written as $\{x\}$ because it's always positive, and its period is $1$.

Let the required period be $T$. So, $$[x+T]^2+\sqrt{\{x+T\}^2}=[x]^2+\sqrt{\{x\}^2}$$
$$\implies([x]+T)^2+\sqrt{\{x\}^2}=[x]^2+\sqrt{\{x\}^2}$$
$$\implies[x]^2+T^2+2T[x]+\{x\}=[x]^2+\{x\}$$
$$\implies T^2+2T[x]=0$$
$$\implies T+2[x]=0$$
$$\implies T=-2[x]$$

Since $T\gt0\implies[x]\lt0$. For minimum $T$, $[x]$ should be maximum i.e. $-1$. So, $T=2$

But I am not able to confirm it. $[x+2]^2+\{x+2\}=[x]^2+4+4[x]+\{x\}$. Not getting $[x]^2+\{x\}$

Comment: you considered $[x]=-1$ $\implies$ $4+4[x]=0$

Comment: This function is larger than the increasing function $(x-1)^2$ when $x>1$. How can it be periodic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \lfloor x\rfloor^2+\sqrt{\{x\}^2}=\infty$. Therefore it cannot be periodic.

Comment: Let $f(x)=[x]^2, g(x)=\{x\}$. $g(x)$ is periodic, $f(x)$ is not. So, $f(x)+g(x)$ is aperiodic. Does this logic always hold?

Comment: @aarbee No: take two periodic functions $f_1$, $f_2$ such that $f_1+f_2$ isn't periodic. Then, $g=f_1$ and $f=-f_1-f_2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks Gae, that helps.